# What is the highest IQ you can earn in one episode?

Tags: indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade

Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (graphic adventure) had an IQ (Indy Quotient) system that rewarded you depending on how you solved a puzzle.

The IQ, a numeric value, was split into 2 values:

- Episode - How many points you have earned on this playthrough
- Series - How many points you have earned across all playthroughs

You cannot earn all available series points in one playthrough.  This gave you the incentive of replaying the game to explore alternative solutions for problems.

Was is the highest episode IQ possible and how do you earn it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maximum Series Score: 800** (source = official hint book)

**Maximum Episode Score: 506**

You cannot get the maximum `series` score in one playthrough.  I have added general notes regarding where to make additional saves and possible routes in each section below.

I have gone into more detail for getting the maximum `episode` score for each section.

*Barnett College (15)*

Simply make sure you do both ways of getting past the students.  You will need to find the real diary before setting off to Venice.  This is also the maximum `series` points you can gain from this section in the game.

- Get past the students by calming them down (third dialog choice) (5)
- Get past the students by telling them about the geology professor (10)

*Venice (30)*

You need to find Hitler's book and the plane guide in the library.  Make sure you look at the shield before leaving the catacombs - nothing else should be missable, and these are the maximum `series` points possible too.

- Enter the catacombs (10)
- Pull the plug to empty the pool in the catacombs (5)
- Get past the statues in the catacombs (5)
- Open the xylophone door (5)
- Look at the shield of the dead knight (5)

*Brunwald Castle (176)*

In short, you are bluffing past everyone then defeating them if they reappear (switch clothes to get their attention).  There is only one exception and that is you must not attack the guard outside the "chairs room" (first walking guard you encounter).  He needs to catch you once you have opened the door for Indy's father.

This method is extremely hard to pull off because of the fighting.  You have a medical kit somewhere in the castle that helps but also save before each fight.  You will need to bluff through each floor then fight your way back down before rescuing Indy's father.  This is because by the time only one standing guard is left, he will head straight for you (only restricted to their current floor).

There is no way to gain maximum `series` points from this section in one playthrough so ideally make a save right before you leave the catacombs (if you want to get the full 800 `series` score too).  You are missing out on 3 fights (the butler, the guard who takes the painting, and the guard who takes the book all give less points than bluffing, giving the painting and bluffing, respectively), 1 bluff (the painting guard gives more points for seeing the painting), the option to give Vogel the fake diary (which means you miss out on Berlin) and the ability to escape undetected (again, missing out Berlin but also the chairs puzzle).  Taking any of these routes will give you lower `episode` score.

For maximum `episode` score:

- Talk past Butler (5)
- Bluff past guard A (2) *drunk guard*
- Knock out guard A (1)
- Bluff past guard B (5) *do not knock this guard out afterwards - he needs to catch you at the end*
- Bluff past guard C (5)
- Knock out guard C (3)
- Bluff past guard E (8)
- Knock out guard E (5)
- Bluff past guard F (8)
- Knock out guard F (5)
- Bluff past guard G (8)
- Knock out guard G (5)
- Bluff past guard H (15) *you won't get the chance of meeting him again after passing him the book*
- Bluff past guard I (8)
- Knock out guard I (5)
- Bluff past guard J (15) *the big guard who knocks you down in 2-3 punches*
- Bluff past guard K (8)
- Knock out guard K (5)
- Open the vault in the castle (10)
- Disable the castle alarm system (25)
- Whip the loose brick on the castle exterior (5)
- Open Henry's locked door (5)
- Escape from the chairs in the castle (15)

*Berlin (45)*

A very short section of the game, but you need Vogel to take the real diary to trigger this route.  Alternatives including fighting through the checkpoint, punching Hitler or getting him to sign the diary (all offer less points).  You cannot get all `series` points on offer in one playthrough so potentially save right before heading to Berlin.

- Bluff past checkpoint 1 (5)
- Give Hitler the travel pass to sign (40)

*Biplane (50)*

The key to this part is getting shot down by the very first plane so you can go through every available checkpoint.  You have 7 checkpoints that give out more points than if you went through the zeppelin route.  As suggested for other sections, you can save before choosing to use the biplane or the zeppelin.  The zeppelin has probably the hardest fight in the game (the ticket collector) plus the escape to the zeppelin's plane is filled with many Nazis and therefore more fights.

If you want the maximum `series` score you will also need a playthrough where you start the biplane in the airport and shoot down ALL planes.  You can only take 12 hits so good luck (this part is also very hard).

- Steal tickets from the man in the airport (5)
- Start the biplane (10)
- Bluff past checkpoint 2 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 3 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 4 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 5 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 6 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 7 (5)
- Bluff past checkpoint 8 (5)

*Grail Temple (190)*

The only thing you need to worry about is the final section after saving your father.  Everything else before that is mandatory.  Also, once you enter the temple you cannot save so make sure you save before entering.

The final choice consists of 2 other alternatives that offer points (if you want the maximum `series` score too).  Let Elsa die then either return the Grail to the crusader or just leave the temple.  There are other possible endings but they offer no extra points.

- Pass the first Grail trial (the Breath of God) (20)
- Pass the second Grail trial (the Name of God) (20)
- Pass the third Grail trial (the Path of God) (20)
- Get the Grail back to Henry (30)
- Pick up the Grail before Elsa gets it, give it to the Grail Knight (100)

Sum of totals:

- Barnett College (15)
- Venice (30)
- Brunwald Castle (176)
- Berlin (45)
- Bi-Plane (50)
- Grail Temple (190)
- **GRAND TOTAL = 506**

*The descriptions of each event that gives score has been copied from the hint book.  Bluff means talk your way through a guard.  Some guards can be bluffed multiple ways (but will give out the same set of points for being bluffed either way).  Checkpoint 2 is the first checkpoint after getting shot down as the numbering scheme includes the checkpoint you go through getting into Berlin.  Guard letters are ordered by the order you should meet them in when going through main routes of the castle.  It is possible to miss a guard by talking alternative routes or walking through a corridor when the guard is patrolling away from you.*